# Using reflection to customize private field of superclass

Tags: java

I am running into a problem trying to modify the behavior of my superclass' private fields from the sub-class (The superclass wasn't designed to be extended and I can't change that).

Basically, what I have is :

```
public class OrthoCanvas {
    private OrthoView xy, xz, zy;

    public class OrthoView { ... }
}
```

And I want to do something like that :

```
public class CustomOrthoCanvas extends OrthoCanvas {
    public CustomOrthoCanvas { 
        // Sets superclass xy, xz, zy to instances of CustomOrthoView
        // This seem to work fine (I'm using reflection to change the fields)
    }

    public class CustomOrthoView extends OrthoView { ... }
}
```

As I said, the reflection seems to work (I'm building CustomOrthoView). But, for the moment, I didn't override any method, and my constructor is just super(whatever), and a Sysout to check what I'm doing. Yet, the original behavior of OrthoView just disappeared, and nothing is working.

Did I make a mistake in my code or is this something more related to my specific case ?

Thanks a lot

Edit : I've just thought that it would be easier if I showed you how I used reflection, so there it is :

```
Field fieldXY = null;
Field fieldXZ = null;
Field fieldZY = null;
try {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
    fieldXY = Class.forName(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()).getDeclaredField("xy");
    fieldXZ = Class.forName(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()).getDeclaredField("xz");
    fieldZY = Class.forName(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()).getDeclaredField("zy");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    System.out.println("-- No such field --");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    System.out.println("-- Security failure --");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("-- Class not found --");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

fieldXY.setAccessible(true);
fieldXZ.setAccessible(true);
fieldZY.setAccessible(true);

try {
    fieldXY.set(this, new CustomOrthoView(this, DimensionId.Z));
    fieldXZ.set(this, new CustomOrthoView(this, DimensionId.Y));
    fieldZY.set(this, new CustomOrthoView(this, DimensionId.X));                
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("-- Illegal argument --");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    System.out.println("-- Illegal access --");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Edit2 : This is a simplified behavior of the superclass :

```
public class Orthoviewer {
    // This class creates a canvas to display an image

    public class OrthoCanvas {
        // This class represents how an image is displayed
        // It implements listeners (to navigate through the image for
        // example), and ways to refresh the image

        public class OrthoView extends JPanel {
           // This class displays one part of the image (one plane)
           // To represent a 3D point by the intersection of the three corresponding planes
           // It has an attribute which indicates its dimension 
           // (X is for ZY plane, Y for XZ plane etc)
           // It overrides the method paintComponent to draw itself

            public class ImageCache implements Runnable {
               // This handles the image to display on the corresponding plane
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `Class.forName(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName())` and not just `this.getClass().getSuperclass()`?

Comment: No particular reason, I just originally had problems with that line, that I corrected and didn't change after that

Comment: Alright. Well, it looks to me like your reflection is working (although I suggest using only one `try` block, because if one statement fails, you want them all to abort). I think we'll need to see the code of the `OrthoCanvas` class...

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't be very helpful, this is a class for an external application (So I don't know if I have the right to do so), which rely on multiple other classes of this application, and is pretty long (900+ lines) ... I will edit my post to try to give an approximation of its behavior though

Comment: Well, I believe the error to be in some code you haven't shown us. My guess would be that one of the methods you override makes some required method call that you left off. But I really can't tell without the code. And if you're not authorised to release it, you'll just have to debug it piece for piece, to see which lines are never reached or which values are different than expected.

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to do just that, thanks for your help